# Get newly created id of a record before redirecting page

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I would like to retrieve the id of a newly created record using javascript when I click on save button and just before redirecting page.

Do you have any idea please ?

Thank you !

Comment: This requires sending an asynchronous message to the server, creating the record and responding with the record id. Look into Ajax and handling success/failures on the client side.

Comment: What particular Version of Sugar / SuiteCRM and what particular modules (if not all), do you need this for?

Comment: I resolved this by using logic hook (after save), for your information, I am using Sugar 6.5 no matter the version of suitecrm.

Thank you !

Comment: @Hachim Ah, so no javascript after all x) Glad to hear you could solve it yourself :)

Comment: Yes, I wanted a solution with javascript the first time, but since I found this solution using only php with sugar hooks, I think that this is enough for me. So After all thank you very much Jay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this by using logic hook (after save), for your information, I am using Sugar 6.5 no matter the version of suitecrm.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in Sugar 7 would be by overriding the CreateView.

Here an example of a CustomCreateView that outputs the new id in an alert-message after a new Account was successfully created, but before Sugar gets to react to the created record.

`custom/modules/Accounts/clients/base/views/create/create.js`:

```js
({
    extendsFrom: 'CreateView',

    // This initialize function override does nothing except log to console,
    // so that you can see that your custom view has been loaded.
    // You can remove this function entirely. Sugar will default to CreateView's initialize then.
    initialize: function(options) {
        this._super('initialize', [options]);
        console.log('Custom create view initialized.');
    },

    // saveModel is the function used to save the new record, let's override it.
    // Parameters 'success' and 'error' are functions/callbacks.
    // (based on clients/base/views/create/create.js)
    saveModel: function(success, error) {

        // Let's inject our own code into the success callback.
        var custom_success = function() {
                // Execute our custom code and forward all callback arguments, in case you want to use them.
                this.customCodeOnCreate(arguments)
                // Execute the original callback (which will show the message and redirect etc.)
                success(arguments);
        };

        // Make sure that the "this" variable will be set to _this_ view when our custom function is called via callback.
        custom_success = _.bind(custom_success , this);

        // Let's call the original saveModel with our custom callback.
        this._super('saveModel', [custom_success, error]);
    },

    // our custom code
    customCodeOnCreate: function() {
        console.log('customCodeOnCreate() called with these arguments:', arguments);
        // Retrieve the id of the model.
        var new_id = this.model.get('id');
        // do something with id
        if (!_.isEmpty(new_id)) {
            alert('new id: ' + new_id);
        }
    }
})
```

I tested this with the Accounts module of Sugar 7.7.2.1, but it should be possible to implement this for all other *sidecar* modules within Sugar.
However, this will **not** work for modules in **b**ack**w**ard-**c**ompatibility mode (those with `#bwc` in their URL).

Note: If the module in question already has its own `Base<ModuleName>CreateView`, you probably should extend from `<ModuleName>CreateView` (no `Base`) instead of from the default `CreateView`.

Be aware that this code has a small chance of breaking during Sugar upgrades, e.g. if the default `CreateView` code receives changes in the `saveModel` function definition.

Also, if you want to do some further reading on extending views, there is an SugarCRM dev blog post about this topic: https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2014/05/28/extending-view-javascript-in-sugarcrm-7/